# How to do batch upload to AWS S3 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an C# console app where I want to upload multiple files(roughly ~20k files in single run with each file less than 5 mb) (not multi-part) to S3 bucket . One way is to call PutObjectRequest in for each loop but i don`t think so its most effiecient way of doing so.

Is there any better way of uploading multiple files to S3?

*I have all files in a local hard disk , where I have to change file name before uploading*

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upload multiple files in a single request, however, you can easily upload multiple files in parallel.

The simplest way would be use the [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)